How to represent X^2/Y (X and Y are matrices) in cvxpy respecting DCP rules?
I have a convex problem for maximizing -X^2/Y in cvxpy, where X and Y are matrices. I know that quad_over_lin is not elementwise. How can I write it in a acceptable way for cvxpy?
I used loops and quad_over_lin. But it increased run time dramatically.

If they are matrices then how does X^2/Y evaluate to a scalar to be used as an objective? Not clear what you actually need to achieve.

How about
constraints = [Z == cp.square(X) / Y]
problem = cp.Problem(objective, constraints)

? It will create the X^2/Y space with element wise constraint.
